# Android appcompat-v7: ActionBar$NavigationMode not found

Tags: android, android-appcompat, transfuse

Since I've upgraded to appcompat-v7 v21, I get the following compilation errors:

Exception in thread "pool-117-thread-1" com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for android.support.v7.app.ActionBar$NavigationMode not found.

Could this be related to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-on-android/zVhoIBqfzZk?

In case this is relevant: I'm using Android Transfuse.

Comment: Navigation modes, like tab and list navigation, were deprecated in the L developer preview for the native action bar. It's possible that AppCompat just removed them entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the info about deprecation. The strange thing is that I don't use it anywhere in my ow code. Guess I'll have to check whether any of my libraries does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this bug is fixed in the final v21 SDK.